# Howto enable hibernate bytecode enhancement WITHOUT Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a plain java project using Hibernate / JPA. No Spring. No J2EE. And i want to enable runtime bytecode enhancement.
A custom class loader is already inside the project so i think i could use org.hibernate.bytecode.spi.InstrumentedClassLoader.InstrumentedClassLoader(ClassLoader, ClassTransformer). But how to get the needed ClassTransformer? Or am i on the wrong track?

Comment: What is the initial problem that you try to solve?

Comment: lazy loading of a oneToOne relationship and use of automatic collection management

Comment: Maybe you mean [bytecode enhancement](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement)?

Comment: exactly. edited.

Comment: You should use maven or gradle plugin as described in the linked above documentation.

Comment: i want runtime enhancement NOT build time enhancement. So that my local start configurations use the same bytecode as the productive code

Comment: And actually it is not necessary for `@OneToOne` lazy loading (only for lazy attribute loading).

Comment: I am afraid that there are no standard/documented ways for the `runtime enhancement`

Comment: *And actually it is not necessary for @OneToOne lazy loading (only for lazy attribute loading).* It is: unless the association is marked as non-optional then `OneToOne` in hibernate is always eager.

Answer (score 0):

works if a ClassFileTransformerAdapter is added as transformer in the premain of a javaagent.
(see  http://appcrawler.com/wordpress/2013/01/02/simple-byte-code-injection-example-with-javassist/)

needs "-javaagent:enhancer.jar" as Vm Argument

```
public class EnhancerMain {
  public static void premain(String agentArguments, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    System.out.println("install enhancer");
    instrumentation.addTransformer(new ClassFileTransformerAdapter(new EnhancingClassTransformerImpl(new DefaultEnhancementContext())));
  }
}

public class ClassFileTransformerAdapter implements ClassFileTransformer {

  private final ClassTransformer classTransformer;

  public ClassFileTransformerAdapter(ClassTransformer classTransformer) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(classTransformer);
    this.classTransformer = classTransformer;
  }

  public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) {
    if (className.startsWith("java/")) {
      return null;
    }
    if (className.startsWith("sun/")) {
      return null;
    }
    if (className.startsWith("com/sun/")) {
      return null;
    }
    if (className.startsWith("javax/")) {
      return null;
    }
    try {
      byte[] transformed = this.classTransformer.transform(loader, className, classBeingRedefined, protectionDomain, classfileBuffer);
      return transformed;
    } catch (IllegalClassFormatException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Error enhancing class: " + className, e);
    }
  }
}
```

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Premain-Class: com.enhancer.EnhancerMain
```